# Calling a specific Pandas Dataframe from user input to use in a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-input, shapes

This might have been answered, but I can't quite find the right group of words to search for to find the answer to the problem I'm having.

**Situation**:
I have a several data frames that could be plugged into a function. The function requires that I name the data frame so that it can take the shape.

```
def heatmap(table, cmap=cm.inferno, vmin=None, vmax=None, inner_r=0.25, pie_args={}:
     n, m = table.shape
```

I want the user to be able to specify the data frame to use as the table like this:

```
table_name= input('specify Table to Graph: ')
heatmap(table_name)
```

**Expectation**: If the user input was TableXYZ then the variable table_name would reference TableXYZ so the function would be able to find the shape of TableXYZ to use that information in other parts of the function.

**What actually happens**: When I try to run the code I get an "AttribureError: 'str' has not attribute 'shape'." I see that the table_name input is a string object, but I'm trying to reference the data frame itself, not the name.

I feel like I'm missing a step to turn the user's input to something the function can actually take the shape of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend assigning each of your dataframes to a dictionary, then retrieving the dataframe by name from the dictionary to pass it to the `heatmap` function.

For example:

```
df_by_name = {"df_a": pd.DataFrame(), "df_b": pd.DataFrame()}
table_name= input('specify Table to Graph: ')
df = df_by_name[table_name]
heatmap(df)
```

Replace `pd.DataFrame()` in the first line with the actual data frames that you want to select from.

Comment: you can also use `list` to store dataframe using `df_list = [pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame()]` then call it using number of index `df_list[0]`. but that would mean user input must be converted into integer

Comment: or just in case you want to save memory, you can just assign the location into a dictionary or list then call it
`paths = {'df_a':'/graph1.csv','df_b':'/grapgh2.csv'}`, `table_name = input('specify Table to graph: ')`,`df = pd.DataFrame(paths[table_name])`,`heatmap(df)`

Comment: @Matthew THANKS! that worked like a charm and was exactly what I needed.